# NodeJS app not answering any request on GAE while working locally

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, angular-universal

I'm trying to develop an Angular Universal app to be deployed on a Google App Engine NodeJS standard environment.

The app works fine locally by running `node server.js`.

When deploying to GAE, however, the page keeps loading and it ultimately fails. In the Google Cloud Console Logs viewer I see this message: `Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)`.

In the `package.json` the start command is `"node server.js"`, while in the app.yaml I declare only the following: `runtime: nodejs8`.

The server code (in TS, packed as JS with WebPack):

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import * as ngUniversal from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as detector from 'spider-detector';
import * as appServer from '../dist/server/main.js';
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');

const ROOT = path.resolve();

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

// Server-side rendering
function angularRouter(req, res): void {
  res.render('index', { req, res });
}

// Enable compression
app.use(compression());

// Check if the user is a bot
app.use(detector.middleware());

// Root route before static files, or it will serve a static index.html, without pre-rendering
app.get('/', angularRouter);

// Serve the static files generated by the CLI (index.html, CSS? JS, assets...)
app.use(express.static('client'));

// Configure Angular Express engine
app.engine('html', ngUniversal.ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: appServer.AppServerModuleNgFactory
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(ROOT, 'client'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

In the Google Cloud Console Logs viewer I successfully see "Listening on http://localhost:3000".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution, in case it helps I'll post it here. The `port` on which express engine listens for requests (on GAE) must be defined with `process.env.PORT`

So, instead of

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

It must be:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for following up with the answer. Solved my problem! 